# CMake: Two libraries, same location of shared objects, one is not found at runtime

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build a C library `libmy` that depends on an external library `libext`. Both `libmy` and `libext` use CMake. Further, `libext` actually produces two shared objects, `libext1.so` and `libext2.so`, both of which are needed by `libmy`.

First, I install `libext` with a custom CMake module, under `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ext`. The process is successful and I end up with the following tree:

```
${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
└── ext
    └── lib
        ├── libext1.so
        └── libext2.so
```

In order to test `libmy`, I build some test cases under target `mytest`, which links to shared objects `libmy.so`, `libext1.so` and `libext2.so`.

The build process of all the targets ends successfully. But when I try to run `mytest`, I get the famous *cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*, but only for `libext1.so`, while `libext2.so` is correctly found. However, what is **very** curious, is that both `libext1.so` and `libext2.so` are located in the same path, and `libext2.so` is indeed linked successfully at runtime. This is what `LD_DEBUG=libs mytest` prints:

```
10703:  find library=libext2.so [0]; searching
10703:   search path=/usr/local/lib:/home/user/mylib/build/ext/lib:x86_64:      (RUNPATH from file src/test/mytest)
10703:    trying file=/usr/local/lib/libext2.so
10703:    trying file=/home/user/mylib/build/ext/lib/libext2.so
10703:      
10703:  find library=libext1.so [0]; searching
10703:   search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
10703:    trying file=/usr/local/lib/libext1.so
10703:   search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64:[...truncated long search path (/home/user/mylib/build/ext/lib is not here)...]:/usr/lib      (system search path)
10703:    trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64/libext1.so
          ...
10703:    trying file=/usr/lib/haswell/libext1.so
10703:    trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64/libext1.so
10703:    trying file=/usr/lib/libext1.so
10703:  
src/test/myest: error while loading shared libraries: libext1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, for some reason, to look for `libext1.so`, the system search path is used (which does not include the path to the external library), while for `libext2.so` the RUNPATH is used (which does have the correct path).

The CMake module where I build the external library basically does this:

```
include(ExternalProject)
set(EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ext)

ExternalProject_Add(extproject
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/ext/ext.git
  CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION})

include_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include)
link_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/lib)

set(EXT_INCLUDE_DIR ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include)
set(EXT1_LIBRARY ext1)
set(EXT2_LIBRARY ext2)
```

And the CMakeLists.txt file where `mytest` is built contains:

```
add_executable(mytest mytest.cpp)
target_include_directories (mytest
  PUBLIC
  ${EXT_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(mytest
  my
  ${EXT1_LIBRARY}  
  ${EXT2_LIBRARY})
add_test(NAME mytest COMMAND mytest)
```

**Disclaimer**: I gave a simplification of the scenario, as the library is rather large and the build process contains several other components. But hopefully this is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a bit subtle.

Turns out that `libext2.so` internally also depends on `libext1.so`. This information is not shown by `LD_LEBUG=libs mytest`, so I thought that the dependency on `libext1.so` came directly from `libmy.so`, which indeed also needs it. However, running `LD_DEBUG=all mytest` outputs:

```
11540:  file=libext1.so [0];  needed by /home/user/mylib/build/external/lib/libext2.so [0]
```

That is why setting the RPATH or RUNPATH for all targets of `libmy` did not have any effect, I guess because the RPATH/RUNPATH for `libext` is set internally by the CMake of that project, and thus independent to the way I build `libmy`.

Since I don't want to modify the CMake scripts of `libext` (I want to use the default ones by that project), all I can do (afaik) is to pass extra arguments to the `ExternalProject_Add` command. The following works:

```
include(ExternalProject)
set(EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ext)

ExternalProject_Add(extproject
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/ext/ext.git
  CMAKE_ARGS 
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/lib)

include_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include)
link_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_RPATH}/lib)

set(EXT_INCLUDE_DIR ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include)
set(EXT1_LIBRARY ext1)
set(EXT2_LIBRARY ext2)
```

(Note the extra **`-DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/lib`** argument to the `ExternalProject_Add` instruction.)

That sets the RPATH so that `libext2.so` can find `libext1.so` at runtime.